# Image is not displayed if there is no prefix http:// in react-native

Tags: image, react-native

I am showing list of images in react native.Since some images are not showed I figured out that images those are not having http:// as prefix are not showing up. What should we do in this case ?

```
<Image
          style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
          source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
 />
```

For the above case it is displaying. But not for the below case

```
<Image
              style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
              source={{uri: 'facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using a url to fetch an image then the syntax is

```
 <Image
          style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
          source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
 />
```

But if you want to use an image from the local directory then use:

```
<Image
          style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
          source={require('./img/favicon.png')}
/>
```

Refer [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html) doc for more info.

Tip: I would request you to share more insight , maybe show a snippet of your code so that the answers can be more helpful.